# How can receive a value from my Login.cs to MasterPageDetail?

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform

When i logged in to app i need to receive the code and username from a dataset, but when i sent those values from my LoginPage.cs to my MasterPage.cs it is received NULL. What im doing wrong?

I have a Class called "Login" which receive the value, but doesnt receive them.

```
/*Code in the LoginPage.cs*/
var VService = DependencyService.Get<IntValidateLogin>();
string resultC = VService.UserCode(txtUser.Text, txtPwd.Text);
string resultN = VService.UserName(txtUser.Text, txtPwd.Text);
if (resultC == "FALSE" || resultN == "FALSE")
{
await DisplayAlert("Alerta", "Usted no tiene permisos para ingresar a la Aplicación Smart. Favor verifique sus credenciales", "Aceptar");
}
else
{
Login lc = new Login
{
LoginUserCode = resultC,
LoginUserName = resultN
};
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Views.MenuPage(), false);

/*Controller*/

public class Login
{
public string LoginUserCode { get; set; }
public string LoginUserName { get; set; }
}

/*MasterDetailPage.cs*/

Login lc;
public MenuPageDetail()
{
InitializeComponent();
lblName.Text = lc.LoginUserName; /*Here its the error because its null when the activity starts and it chashes*/
}
```

/*MenuPage Code*/

```
public partial class MenuPage : MasterDetailPage
    {

        public MenuPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MasterPage.ListView.ItemSelected += ListView_ItemSelected;
        }

        private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = e.SelectedItem as MenuPageMenuItem;
            if (item == null)
                return;

            var page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType);
            page.Title = item.Title;

            Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
            IsPresented = false;

            MasterPage.ListView.SelectedItem = null;
        }
```

/*XML*/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SmartAPPVB.Views.MenuPage"
             xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:SmartAPPVB.Views">
  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <pages:MenuPageMaster x:Name="MasterPage" />
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
      <x:Arguments>
        <pages:MenuPageDetail />
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Comment: your are creating a Login object but then you do not do anything with it.  You are not passing it to MenuPage

Comment: @Jason MenuPage.cs its just a masterpage witch loads the MenuDetail like parent and child, why do i need to pass it through MenuPage?

Comment: because LoginPage calls MenuPage.  LoginPage does not have a direct reference to MenuDetail.  You could structure your code differently, but based on what you posted this is how I would do it.

Comment: @Jason ok, i will try to manage it like you said.

Answer (score 0):

you actually need to pass your `Login` object to `MenuPage`

```
Login lc = new Login
{
  LoginUserCode = resultC,
  LoginUserName = resultN
};

await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Views.MenuPage(lc), false);
```

then in `MenuPage`'s constructor

```
public MenuPage(Login login) 
{
  // do something with login here
}
```